# My select query is not working in ajax

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

here is the code which i use to fetch all medicines name from database in dropdown list

```
  <?php 
    $selmed = mysql_query("SELECT mnam FROM med");
    echo '<select onChange="getQty();" id="pf5" name="recmed">';
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($selmed)) 
    {echo '<option value="'.$row['mnam'].'">'.$row['mnam'].'</option>';} 
  ?>
```

Now I want to fetch quantity against a specific medicine from database for that i use ajax as follow

```
var medn = $('#pf5').val();
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "getqty.php",
  data: {
    mednam: medn
  },
  success: function(data) {
    $("#val").html(data);
  }
});
}
```

and here is my getqty.php file where i think i am making some mistake in query

```
<?php
include('connection.php');
$recm = $_POST['mednam'];
$rmq = mysql_query("SELECT mqty FROM med WHERE mnam ='$recm'");
echo $rmq;
?>
```

and the area where i want result on changing value shows "Resource id #5"

Comment: Please dont use [the `mysql_` database extension](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php), it
is deprecated (gone for ever in PHP7)
Specially if you are just learning PHP, spend your energies learning the `PDO` database extensions.
[Start here](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

Comment: Your script is at risk of [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)
Have a look at what happened to [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/) Even
[if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string)

Comment: what is the output you are getting now?

Comment: Your issue is you are not processing the result of the `mysql_query()` All that does is execute the query on the server. You have to then fetch the rows that are returned `mysql_fetch_assoc()` for example

Comment: my output is **Resource id #5**

Comment: you don't do select queries in ajax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following line does not echo result data

```
$rmq = mysql_query("SELECT mqty FROM med WHERE mnam ='$recm'");
echo $rmq;
```

Use while loop to echo all results

```
$rmq = mysql_query("SELECT mqty FROM med WHERE mnam ='$recm'");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($rmq)) {
    // echo fields with
    // $row['field_name'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You've made the query, but not `$rmq` can not be interpreted as the data you want until you process it

```
$rmq = mysql_query("SELECT mqty FROM med WHERE mnam ='$recm'");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($rmq)) { //Not necessarily a while-loop, depends on what data you're expecting
    $var = $row['x'];
    echo $var;
}
```

Please consider using PDO, or at the very least MySQLi